# Указать последний элемент массива

Tags: php

Я хочу выбрать последний элемент массива, но получаю ошибку undefined offset: 1. Если укажу ключ руками, то норм, а подставлять $last не получается

У меня есть скрипт по которому я получаю массив с данными из crm. И мне нужно выбрать последний элемент. Чтобы получить его id.

```html
// Пример массива
$clients = [
            'users' => [
                '0' => [
                    'id' => '1212',
                    'phone' => '22204490122',
                    'message' => 'dddd',
                ],
                '1' => [
                    'id' => '4111',
                    'phone' => '22204490122',
                    'message' => 'aaaa',
                ],
            ]
        ];

$last = count($clients) - 1;

$clients['users'][$last]['id'];
```

Comment: `$last = count($clients['users']) - 1;` очевидно

Answer (score 3):

Считать надо не число элементов в массиве `$clients`, а число элементов в массиве `$clients['users']`:

```
$last = count($clients['users']) - 1;
$clients['users'][$last]['id'];
```

Начиная с **php7.3** есть также [`array_key_last`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-last.php):

```
$last = array_key_last($clients['users']);
$clients['users'][$last]['id'];
```

[Демка](https://3v4l.org/Xn2TU).